# Redirect all sub URLs in index.php

Tags: php, redirect, subdirectory

I have the following URL structure: www.domain.com/test/anyString

I want that all requests of www.domain.com/test are redirected to another site. But only these who have /test/ in their request.

I was able to perform a redirect with www.domain.com but not with any subdirectory. My code so far:

```
//if our domain is called
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.domain.com"){
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
//$webOS   = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");

//do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone ){
//browser reported as an iPhone/iPod touch -- do something here
header("Location: https://itunes.apple.com/de"); exit; 
}else if($iPad){
//browser reported as an iPad -- do something here
header("Location: https://itunes.apple.com/de"); exit; 
}else if($Android){
//browser reported as an Android device -- do something here
header("Location: http://play.google.com/"); exit; 
}else{
header("Location: http://www.google.de"); exit; 
}
}
```

But this only works for the complete host.

Comment: i switched to creating a .htaccess file. See below. Works perfectly for.

Answer (score 1):

Use apache rewrite engine, With out writing any PHP code, you can do it. Please click below link for the same

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

For eg:

> RewriteEngine  on
>
> RewriteRule    "^/text"  "/someurl"  [R]

Answer (score 0):

Hm i tested a little bit around:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipod|ipad" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)test(.*)$ http://www.apple.com [R=301,L]

#redirect to android market
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)test(.*)$ https://play.google.com [R=301,L]
```